# How to Access an AWS Private Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, private, credentials, bucket

I'm a beginner in AWS and I'm trying some functions, if you can help me I thank.

I received a file of credentials to access a private bucket, but I don't know how to access that bucket, whether it is by CMD or the internet itself, I tested a public bucket and through the browser I can access these files by downloading directly from the link, but I would like to know how do I access this private bucket with the credentials I received

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Install](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv1.html) the [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), [configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html) it with your credentials, then [use](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3.html) the awscli with S3.

Here are a couple of examples:

- `aws s3 ls mybucket` (list bucket)
- `aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/dogs/bingo.png .` (copy file from S3)